# Pass by value and pass by reference in C# curly bracket

Tags: c#

Why do I keep getting "} expected" every time I run my program? I don't think I am missing any curly bracket. Could it be something else?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] anArray = new int[] {30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110};

            var byVal = anArray[0];
            Console.WriteLine("by value: " + byVal);

            ref int byRef = anArray[0];
            Console.WriteLine("by reference: " + byRef);


       }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show the us the exact/full error that you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

It's failing to parse your code (not sure why it's picking up on `}`).

This is invalid C# code

```
ref int byRef = anArray[0];
```

You can't define a variable as `ref`. You use it when passing parameters to a method. For example:

```
void Main()
{
    int b = 6;
    ChangeIt(ref b);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}

void ChangeIt(ref int a)
{
    a = 5;
}
```

Will print out `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the meaning of `ref` keyword: it is used to pass parameters by reference, not to make references to local variables.

C# determines to make a variable a reference or a value based on that variable's type: primitive types and `struct`s are value types, so variables corresponding to these types store values. Classes, on the other hand, are reference types, so variables of the corresponding type store references.